# How do I use setNdefPushMessage()

Tags: android, nfc

(using 4.1.1 JellyBean on a Nexus S) I am trying to follow [these instructions](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/NfcAdapter.html#setNdefPushMessage%28android.nfc.NdefMessage,%20android.app.Activity,%20android.app.Activity...%29), but the restrictions on in which activities `setNdefPushMessage()` can be used are to me somewhat vague.  Presently my app, which has an activity for handling http requests via:

```
<activity android:name=".HandleUrlActivity"
          android:label="@string/title_handle_url_message" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" /
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:scheme="http" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

crashes with:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: API cannot be called while activity is paused
```

when setNdefPushMessage() is called within HandleUrlActivity().

In what activities can setNdefPushMessage() be used?  Or how can I keep an activity running until the Ndef is served and how do I know when that activity can return/exit?  Calling:

```
    NfcAdapter nfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);
    nfcAdapter.setNdefPushMessage(ndef, this);
    nfcAdapter.wait();
```

gives the above error with or without the wait.  Clearly `setNdefPushMessage()` needs some support mechanisms to handle the wait-for-nfc-receive-capable-device-proximity and then send events and I expected it to block until all this was complete, but apparently it does not.

(`enableForegroundNdefPush/disableForegroundNdefPush` apparently addressed this issue but appear to have been deprecated for ICS/JB with claims that `setNdefPushMessage` handles all this...)

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to do? `setNdefPushMessage()` simply registers a message, it will only be sent when the Android runtime detects a compatible device. You have no control over this, so there is no point in calling `wait()`, etc (generally you shouldn't try to control the activity lifecycle). Calling it in `onCreate()` should work, but not calling it in the constructor when the activity is not yet full constructed and there is no valid `Context`. Generally though, having this in an activity that handles `VIEW` doesn't make much sense, since you can't really control when it will be started, so what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: For now, I'm simply trying to "push" a URL to a remote device.  The user needs to see the screen "block" until a compatible destination device comes near.  The NFC system needs to know to lock out any other NFC actions until this one is complete.  Something needs to create this stasis until the destination device is _removed_ from proximity - hence a period of waiting, followed by a "return to normal" function of some kind.  (btw, the http VIEW intent is triggered by the user selecting a URL, or any other start-the-browser event)

Comment: You cannot do this, since you have no control over the "NFC system". You can only register for inents and specify the NDEF message to be pushed.

Comment: The question is valid regardless of whether or not my example has merit.  I'll clarify my point somewhat further.  The foreground app controls the current NFC action (the default is to send the app URI).  The docs I referenced say setNdefPushMessage overrides this "locking out" the default - a poor choice of words I admit but the meaning is still clear.  So setNdefPushMessage() does not need to block, but clearly I need to do something to keep at least one activity in my app from pausing (and my ndef message from being destroyed until it has been sent).

Comment: The question might be valid, but this cannot be done with the Android SDK (without modifying the OS or at least having system permissions). The user might simply press the home button and your activity(s) will be paused, there is nothing you can do about this. Best you can do is write your own home app that re-starts your activity over and over, but you probably don't want to do this.